# Pegar retorno XMLHttpRequest send

Tags: php, javascript, xmlhttprequest

Boa tarde, estou utilizando o seguinte codigo para fazer upload de imagens:

```
   function uploadImage($form){
        $form.find('.progress-bar')
            .removeClass('progress-bar-success')
            .removeClass('progress-bar-danger');
    var formdata = new FormData($form[0]); //formelement
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    //progress event...
    request.upload.addEventListener('progress',function(e){
        $('.progress').removeClass('hidden');
        var percent = Math.round(e.loaded/e.total * 100);
        $form.find('.progress-bar').width(percent+'%').html(percent+'%');
    });

    //progress completed load event
    request.addEventListener('load',function(e){
        $('.progress').removeClass('active');
        $form.find('.progress-bar').addClass('progress-bar-success').html('Upload completo');
    });

    request.open('post', 'server.php');
    request.send(formdata);

}
```

o arquivo `server.php` contem:

```
<?php
    foreach ($_FILES as $name => $file) {

        $tmp_file = $file['tmp_name'];
        $filename = $file['name'];

        move_uploaded_file($tmp_file, 'uploads_folder/'. $name.$_POST['categoria_nome'].'.jpg');
    }
    return true;
? >
```

Gostaria de saber como pego o `return` do arquivo `server.php` na função de upload?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tens de juntar mais uma oscultador de eventos, para mudanças no `ready state`.

Exemplo:

```
request.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (request.readyState < 4)                             // está à espera de resposta
        console.log('A carregar...');
    else if (request.readyState === 4) {                    // 4 = A resposta do servidor está carregada
        if (request.status == 200 && request.status < 300)  // http status entre 200 e 299 quer dizer sucesso
            alert(request.responseText);                    // ou usa o xhr.responseText de outra maneira
    }
}
```

ou usando `request.addEventListener('readystatechange ', function(){ // etc...`

Para passares resultados do servidor para o cliente podes usar assim:

```
echo '{"done": true, "message": "hello world!"}';
```

e no JavaScript

```
var resObject = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
```

e aí se deres `alert(resObject.message);` vai dar "hello wordl!"

Podes também usar no PHP `json_encode(array);`, mas se é pouca coisa pode ser mais prático como coloquei em cima.

Comment: Além dos arquivos estou enviando outro campos do formulário, Vou inserir no banco dentro do arquivo server.php, Gostaria de retornar algo sem ser a resposta do servidor. Tem como fazer ?

Comment: @MatheusIlário o que queres dizer com `retornar algo sem ser a resposta do servidor`? podes explicar melhor?

Comment: Se a inserção tiver sucesso quero retornar uma variavel com valor true e outra com uma mensagem por exemplo

Comment: @MatheusIlário ok, podes passar um JSON com `json.encode()` no PHP e `JSON.parse()` no JS. Se não sabes como fazer posso colocar aqui um exemplo mais logo.

Comment: ficaria agradecido se puder postar um exemplo

Comment: @MatheusIlário juntei no fim da resposta. Era isso que querias certo?

Comment: Ok Sergio, Muito Obrigado! Na segunda faço o teste! Vlw

Comment: Sergio era isso mesmo! Muito Obrigado.

Comment: @MatheusIlário ótimo! Até breve.